# Basic Random Rolling Dice Java

Tags: java, random

I am trying to write a method rollDice(int number, int nSides) which returns the total result of rolling the number dice with nSides sides.

So for example rollDice(3, 6) should return the result of rolling 3 six-sided dice (adding to a number between 3 and 18 inclusive).

Below method returns negative numbers when I type 1 for `int number` what do I need to do to fix this?

```
public static  int rollDice(int number, int nSides) {
    int num = 0;
      if(nSides >=3)
    {
      for(int i = 0; i < number; i++){
       Random  r = new Random(); 
       int roll = r.nextInt();
       num = num + (roll % nSides)+1;

      }
    }
      else{
          System.out.println("Error num needs to be from 3");

    }
    return num; 
}
```

Comment: Why can't you have a two sided roll e.g. a coin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need to initialize `Random r` and `int roll` once each so I have removed them from the loop. The nextInt(int) method picks an integer from and including 0 to but not including the int. This is known as 0 (inclusive) to int (exclusive), so you have to add 1 to adjust the range to the die. You seem to have known that though I don't know why you used %. Using * to multiply would give you the same number for all the dice which I don't believe you mean to do. Here is one possible implementation of your class:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Dice {

    public static  int rollDice(int number, int nSides)
    { 
        int num = 0;
        int roll = 0;
        Random  r = new Random(); 
        if(nSides >=3) 
        { 
            for(int i = 0; i < number; i++)
            { 
                roll = r.nextInt(nSides)+1;
                System.out.println("Roll is:  "+roll);
                num = num + roll; 
            } 
        } 
        else
        { 
            System.out.println("Error num needs to be from 3"); 
        } 
        return num;  
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Total is: "+rollDice(3, 6));
    }
}
/*
Roll is:  4
Roll is:  1
Roll is:  2
Total is: 7
*/
```

Comment: apcris just out of interest. Can I ask why you have main method here? I   learned it before but I never understood it enough to able to use it.

Comment: A main method is what executes when you run your code. If you only need the method rollDice then you don't need a main method. He includes one here to demonstrate the rollDice function.

Answer (score 13):

`Random.nextInt()` has unpredicable behaviour - it can produce all values possible for an integer, including negative numbers. Use `Random.nextInt(numSides)` instead - it will return an integer from [0,numSides) i.e. including 0 and excluding numSides. To get your desired functionality [1,numSides] use

```
r.nextInt(numSides)+1;
```

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

replace 
 
`int roll = r.nextInt();` 

 with

`int roll = r.nextInt(nSides);`

Comment: You don't need to subtract one from nSides.

Comment: Yes Peter than I also need not to add +1, because it will be taken care in next line. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you use `%` on a negative number you get a negative number.

In this case the solution is simple, use

```
int roll = r.nextInt(nSides) + 1; // 1 to nSizes
num += roll;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this as your rollDice method:

```
public static int rollDice(int number, int nSides) {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        count += (int)(Math.random() * nSides) + 1;
    }
    return count;
}
```